# Mapping a C# property onto a data member's property

Tags: c#, properties, syntactic-sugar

Supposing I have the following structure:

```
public class Inner
{
    public double Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Outer
{
    public double Bar { get; set; }

    private Inner MyInner;
}
```

I want `Outer` to automatically forward `Bar` to `MyInner.Foo`.  Is there any syntactical shortcut?  I'd rather not type

```
public double Bar
{
    get
    {
        return MyInner.Foo;
    }
    set
    {
        MyInner.Foo = value;
    }
}
```

All the time.  My company's code style guide requires newlines for all braces, and my class has several such members.

Comment: I don't think it gets any simpler than that without including the overhead of an automapper library.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much how you do it, and there isn't any syntactical sugar to shorten it. As far as the coding conventions, I would push back; very broad rules like "All code block braces must have newlines" are just waiting for something very simple like this situation to turn into a whitespace mess. But, it's honestly not worth getting yourself fired over if you can't convince them to make exceptions; ReSharper and other refactoring assistants would make your properties look like this anyway.

Comment: It's not really that strict. I'll probably shorten them to one-liners in the end...

Comment: @Lucero - He could one-line the property and eliminate 10 of the 11 lines of his second code block. At the very least he can one-line the getter and setter. The point was that OP's company enforces use of Allman style which led him to wonder whether there was something that didn't require 6 lines worth of braces.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to do this with an automatic property. But with code-snippets you should be able to write that code rather quickly. And if you make a habit of collapsing code (Ctrl + M + O) as I do, it doesn't look too bad either.